# SQL Syntax Error When Exporting DB Using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

sometime recently, I started getting an error message when importing an sql database using PHPMyAdmin. When I go in and export the sql database through PHPMyAdmin, I just select the database I want, hit the export tab, choose custom & then tick the Add Drop Table and then I save the exported database.

Then, just to repeat the error, I go in and drop all the tables. Then when I go to import the database, I get the error message I'm posting below.

A couple of notes before I post the error:

- When I view my PHP Info on the website, it says I'm using PHP Version 5.2.17, which is correct since that's what I've selected when compiling EasyApache
- When my 'sql' export file downloads, it says I'm using PHP Version 5.3.17
- I also just found out that if I export my sql database using SSH, and then import the database using PHPMyAdmin, everything appears to have worked just fine. So it appears the error is with the database exporting currently.

**Error Message:**

Error
There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser. Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are correct and not mis-matched. Other possible failure causes may be that you are uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text area. You can also try your query on the MySQL command line interface. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem. If you still have problems or if the parser fails where the command line interface succeeds, please reduce your SQL query input to the single query that causes problems, and submit a bug report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:
----BEGIN CUT----
eNo1zbEKwjAYBGCh2/8U9wAxNKlByBZKqEKaxKRWcBWHQskm6NubCt54fNzZlELS6AV6CWe9hoCE
EJSnWjdE4ydfnIbiindy/1hXuuaEkBnMYP3EMNsKb0vBGO5n50ylLcXRaBx4yxXFU9wMC3lb6bg4
wi3l9SZn/KDxLPQ7oGb3zxcWUiEE
----END CUT----
----BEGIN RAW----

ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 1 2 11
STR:

MySQL: 5.5.32-cll
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Win MOZILLA 5.0
PMA: 4.0.5
PHP VER,OS: 5.3.17 Linux
LANG: en
SQL:

----END RAW----

SQL query:

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating your phpMyAdmin if you can.  (If its not already the latest)

I can't help with the specific error but if you want to try and find out what is causing it then what I would do is export the data to a file as before.  Clear all the tables manually.  Then edit the file with a decent text editor and split it into pieces.  Then try importing it in a piece at a time until you hit the error.

When you find the piece that is causing your problem you can keep breaking it down until you narrow it down to the individual call that is causing the problem.  Hopefully then you will spot what is wrong.  (And if it is a bug that is not fixed in the latest version of phpMyAdmin - the maintainers would probably appreciate a copy of your findings in a bug report)

Sorry I cannot be any more help.

Comment: Appreciate the help James! And by chopping it into various parts for import, I would just leave all the top heading info in there, and then cut out selections of chunks located within the "--------------" areas basically right?

Answer (score -1):

It's probable that the size of your exported file exceeds the upload limits of your PHP configuration. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq1-16.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marc, the database file in question is only 747 kb though currently.